# AWS Lambda trigger not having cloudfront

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I created a new lambda function but do not see cloudfront as an option in the Triggers. Does anybody know why that might be? Thanks

Comment: What language did you write your Lambda function in?

Comment: I wrote it in JAVA

Answer (score 7):

As per AWS current documentation:

> Make sure that you’re in the US-East-1 (**N. Virginia**) Region. You must
>   be in this Region to create **Lambda@Edge** functions.

See: [AWS Tutorial: Creating a Simple Lambda@Edge Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial.html#lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial-create-function)

[image: Select AWS region]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add from Lambda console. For adding trigger for cache behavior, you need to do it from CloudFront console.

Its is explained in detail here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers-cf-console.html

Comment: Incorrect.  The Lambda console does allow this. 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront's Lambda@Edge integration feature requires that the functions be written in Node.js.  It isn't possible to trigger a function in another language directly from CloudFront.

> You must create functions with the `nodejs6.10` or `nodejs8.10` runtime property.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-lambda-function-configuration

Of course, in the Node.js runtime environment, you have the AWS Javascript SDK available, so if you had a *really* compelling case, you could use that from a Javascript function to invoke another, different Lambda function written in a different language... but it's difficult to imagine a common case where that would make sense, because of the added latency and cost, but I have, for example, used this solution to allow Lambda@Edge to reach inside a VPC -- which can only be done by invoking a second Lambda function (which could be configured to have VPC access) from inside the first (which can't, because Lambda@Edge functions run in the region nearest to the viewer, rather than in a single region, so they will not run inside a VPC).

Comment: Hi Michael,  Thanks for your response. This makes sense why I have been struggling to add it to Cloud Front. Thanks again